# MySQL: How to decrement an unsigned int column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column `unsigned int`, let's name it col1.

I want to decrement the column by a number, if value after decrement is less than 1 then set it to 1. Like this:

```
UPDATE `tbl1` SET `col1` = GREATEST(1, `col1`-3);
```

This works fine, but if col1 is 0 or 1 or 2 and I try to do -3 then MySQL throws an error.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177543/mysql-using-if-then-else-in-mysql-update-or-select-queries) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277339/decrement-value-in-mysql-but-not-negative) but didn't worked.

Comment: What error??  Perhaps related to `UNSIGNED`?

Comment: @RickJames it is, I know, because `UNSIGNED` doesn't allow negative values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `case` clause

```
update tbl1 set col1 =  (case when col1 <= 3 then 1 else (col1 - 3) end);
```

As @RDFozz described :

With the OP's listed code, col1 - 3 must be computed, and since it's an unsigned integer, the result must be an unsigned integer. This code prevents the computation from happening unless the result would actually be an unsigned integer.

**UPDATE :**

Another possible way as suggested by @kondybas

```
update tbl1 set col1 = IF(col1<=3, 1, col1-3);
```

Comment: Excellent point. With the OP's listed code, `col1 - 3` must be computed, and since it's an unsigned integer, the result must be an unsigned integer. Your alternate code prevents the computation from happening unless the result would actually be an unsigned integer.

Comment: The other approach is to use `IF()` function: `SET col1 = IF(col1<3, 1, col1-3)`

Comment: DEatTh and @Kondybas answers are both correct and work as expected, though I prefer Kondybas's answer as it seems slightly more readable to me.

Comment: To match the condition `..if value after decrement is less than 1 then set it to 1.`, then I used `<= 3` instead of `< 3`

Answer (score 2):

> if value after decrement is less than 1 then set it to 1.

Just add a `WHERE` statement

```
UPDATE tbl1
  SET col1 = col1 - 1
WHERE col1 >= 2;
```

Comment: Good answer. But in my case, the `- 1` is a variable number, it could be any number (-1, -2, -3, etc), so how to do it?

Comment: `UPDATE tbl1
  SET col1 = col1 - $var
WHERE col1 >= $var +  1;`

Comment: That doesn't work as expected: if col1 is 2 and I try to do -3, like this: `UPDATE tbl1 SET col1 = col1 - 3 WHERE col1 >= 4;` , then col1 will remain as 2 instead of being updated to 1

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to skin this cat:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET col1 = GREATEST(4, col1) - 3
```

Possibly more efficient:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET col1 = GREATEST(4, col1) - 3
    WHERE col1 > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimum value that an `unsigned int` can have is 0, you cannot set it to negative unless it is signed. You need to implement logic to handle the values in the column so your `GREATEST(1, 'col1'-3)` isn't violating the rule. `CASE WHEN` in that statement may work as well as pulling out a filtered subset of the data with a subquery.

[MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)

[Stack Overflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515613/5149122)

You can also cast your unsigned int as a signed int and then perform the arithmetic.

[Stack overflow reference on casting to signed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733475/5149122)